# How can I execute method of an Object in Arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

My problem is:
I created an Arraylist serviceList

Both service1 and service2 are 2 seperate objects from 2 classes but they have the same "execute" method:

```
public Service1 service1;
public Service2 service2;

/*Then I add element to Arraylist:*/
serviceList.add(0, service1);
serviceList.add(1, service2);

/*then how can I run "excute" method of service1 and service2?
something like this:*/
for(Object service: serviceList){
    service.execute();
}
```

I tried with ArrayList< Class> but it was a deadend.
Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: you declare them as Object, Object doesn't provide an execute method. so either you cast your object within your loop, or you declare them as the right type

Answer (score 3):

Introduce an interface:

```
interface Service {
  void execute();
}

class Service1 implements Service { ... }
class Service2 implements Service { ... }

List<Service> serviceList = ...

for (Service service: serviceList) {
  service.execute();
}
```

Comment: Don't even need an explicit loop with that... `serviceList.forEach(Service::execute)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ArrayList<T> only can accept the declared type T, so you cannot add objects of a different type, say K into the same ArrayList.

**Solution 1**
A solution for your need could be to declare `ArrayList<Object> list` and then add the two services.

**Solution 2**
Now, because you want a common `execute` method, it would be natural for your `Service1` and `Service2` classes to implement some interface, say `Service` to achieve a unique `execute` method implementation for each class. And you can declare your ArrayList as `ArrayList<Service> list`